# Adding touch events to an UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

So I had some code that used the  `touchesBegan:withEvent:, touchesMoved:withEvent:, touchesEnded:withEvent:` functions to accomplish some of my manipulations on the screen. Since everything was done on a separate screen I just overwrote those methods in the ViewController. Now, I would like to port this functionality to work on a separate `UIView`. Since I can not overwrite those functions I tried using the `UIGestureRecognizer` set of classes but I failed as I couldn't find the combination that will trigger specifically when I need it (the press on the screen - `touchesBegan`, while moving - `touchesMoved`, and when the action stopped `touchesEnded`). Reading through SO I managed to find an option - create my custom  view and overwrite the needed methods, but I would like to avoid it as the described functionality shouldn't be always present.

Is there a way I could achieve to trigger 3 functions using `UIGestureRecognizer` that will trigger at start, move and end accordingly or the only possible way to achieve what I want is to create a custom `UIView`?

Comment: What is the problem with `touchesBegan:withEvent` for UIView?

Comment: @anhtu can I overwrite that method without creating a custom class? No, right?

Comment: You're right. Override comes with subclass.